# Upgrade to TortoiseHg 2.0 breaks svn

Tags: svn, tortoisehg, mercurial-extension, tortoisehg-2.0

I just upgraded to TortoiseHg 2.0 and now my Push to / Pull from svn (I have MercurialSvn extension enabled) fails with

> *no compatible bindings available:*
>
> *Subversion 1.5.0 or later required,
>   but no bindings were found Subvertpy
>   0.7.4 or later required, but not found*
>
> *Please install either Subvertpy or the
>   Subversion Python SWIG bindings*

I saw a post elsewhere concerning this error message (although not this specific upgrade scenario) recommending to take Mercurial out of the PATH variable and leave only TortoseHg. I checked this but actually only have TortoiseHg on PATH so cannot use that approach.

I don't particularly want to install anything else on this corporate workstation so don't want/ don't know how to follow the instruction TortoiseHg gives..

If it is the only way then can seomone tell me how to go about installing Subverty or SWIG bindings please?

Better still, can anyone give me a quick fix please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in the new nightly builds. More info in [Missed SVN DLLs in TortoiseHg 2.0](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/229/missed-svn-dlls-in-tortoisehg-20-bundle)

Comment: Ah, thanks Ricardo, I will try this tomorrow when I get into the office. Your answer is greatly appreciated!